# Can \foreach handle list of lists?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code draws the first hexagram of the *I Ching*:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
   hexagram/.pic={
     \foreach \d [count=\n] in {#1}{
       \ifthenelse{\d=0}
         {\draw [yshift=\n*2cm, line width=1cm, purple] (-6,0) -- (-1,0)  (1,0) -- (6,0);}
         {\draw [yshift=\n*2cm, line width=1cm, purple] (-6,0)          --         (6,0);}
     }}
}
\pic at (15,0) {hexagram = {0,0,0,0,0,0}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I try to draw all the remaining 63 hexagrams with a `foreach` I obtain an error, as if `foreach` was not able to cope with lists whose elements are lists: replacing the line

`\pic at (15,0) {hexagram = {0,0,0,0,0,0}};`

with, say,

```
\foreach [count=\n] \m in {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
                           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
                           {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
                           {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
                           {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
                           {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 
                           {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, 
                           {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}}{
\pic at (\n*15,0) {hexagram = \m};
}
```

I obtain a

`./iching2.tex:28: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [}]
./iching2.tex:28: Missing number, treated as zero. [}]`

error. What shall I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to strip off the braces around the internal elements otherwise they are taken as a single entity and cannot be iterated over and also being compared to a number. This can be done in many ways but the easiest is to use `/.expand once` handler. You can also use twice or expanded keys but it is good practice to expand exactly the required times of expansion.

Replacing your inner pic command with

```
\pic at (\n*15,0) {hexagram/.expand once = \m};
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @percusse is perfect.

But in case you want to continue using `{hexagram = \m}` in place of `{hexagram/.expand once = \m}` you can modify the definition of your picture like this :

**Method I.** You can replace

```
\foreach \d [count=\n] in {#1}{
```

with

```
\edef\set{#1}   
\foreach \d [count=\n] in \set{
```

**Method II.** *(based on the @percusse's answer)* You can replace

```
hexagram/.pic={
```

with

```
pics/hexagram/.style={hexaone/.expand once=#1},
hexaone/.pic={
```

The result is always the same :

[image]